# How to take a string of numbers and check if there are any duplicate numbers in python?

Tags: python, numbers, duplicates

How would I write code that will allow me to check for duplicates in a string of numbers.

```
alist = [['123456789', '112345678', '123345678', '859403126']]
(alist[0][0] = no duplicate)
(alist[0][1] = duplicate)
(alist[0][2] = duplicate)
(alist[0][3] = no duplicate)
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Create `set` and compare lengths

```
>>> x = alist[0][0]
>>> len(set(x)) == len(x)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
"".join(set(alist[0][0]))
```

As a result you will get a set of unique letters in the string, and *join()* will join the letters back to a string in arbitrary order. After this operation simply check if new string has the same length as the original one.

Answer (score 0):

this list comprehension

```
dups = [[len(set(el)) != len(el) for el in el0] for el0 in alist]
```

produces

```
[[False, True, True, False]]
```

i.e. `False` for 'no duplicates', `True` for 'duplicates'

In case you really want such literals, use:

```
dups = [[ 'duplicate' if len(set(el)) != len(el) else 'no duplicate' for el in el0] for el0 in alist]
```

which produces

```
[['no duplicate', 'duplicate', 'duplicate', 'no duplicate']]
```

Answer (score 0):

First , I think pacholik's answer is the most easy-understanding one.
Inspird by [this example](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/re.html#checking-for-a-pair) , I provide the following solution

```
import re
alist = [['123456789', '112345678', '123345678', '859403126']]
for i in alist[0]:
    print('alist[0][{}] = '.format(i),'duplicate' if re.search(r'.*?(.).*?\1',i) else 'no duplicate')
```